# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer not filling the fullscreen

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to do a snapchat like camera view, with the camera stream filling all the screen.

Here is the code :

```
func beginSession() {
    var err : NSError? = nil

    // try to open the device
    let videoCapture = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &err)

    if err != nil {
        // Fail silently.  Do better in the real world.
        println("Capture session could not start: \(err?.description)")
        return
    }

    // add video input
    if captureSession.canAddInput(videoCapture) {
        captureSession.addInput(videoCapture)
    }

    // config capture session
    if !captureSession.running {
        // set JPEG output
        stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
        let outputSettings = [ AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG ]
        stillImageOutput!.outputSettings = outputSettings

        // add output to session
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
        }

        // display camera in UI
        let bounds = cameraView.bounds
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        previewLayer?.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), cameraView.frame.width, cameraView.frame.height)
        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

        println(cameraView.frame.height)
        println(previewLayer?.frame.height)
        // start camera
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
}
```

I call begin session in the `viewDidAppear` to be sure all the view settings are applied and i set the necessary constraints on the `cameraView` to be sure it fills the screen.

When I check my logs, I can see that `previewLayer` and `cameraView` have the same dimensions and position.

Here is how it renders :

[image]

Here is the [incriminated view controller](https://github.com/hmazelier/snapClone/blob/master/CameraTest/CameraVC.swift) :

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems like the cameraView frame is not set while you are adding the preview layer frame.

pls try to update the preview layers frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews() function

Comment: It worked ! Thank you, I thought the subviews were layedout already in viewDidAppear !

Comment: it is supposed to be set in the ViewDidAppear() function call....and normally does while using xib's .  But Im sure that it would be set in viewDidLayoutSubviews() , please be sure to only set the frame of your preview layer in this function..not the initialisation itself...
this function may be called again if there are layout changes made in the view